# Smoothen, close and simply surface in very complex objects

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am trying to create a model of wrist bones from a CT scan. The individual bones all have quite a number of holes and an interior structure (bone marrow) that is not relevant, but very hard to remove.
I am now trying to create a smooth surface model from it. Running the smooting modifier will create an acceptable image for most parts, but the many holes are really ugly. I would like to simply the surface (reduce the number of vertices, currently about 33,000) and close the holes.
I tried fixing the holes manually by adding faces, but this doesn't really work well. Since the surface is in continuity with the inside of the bone, finding the boundaries of the holes also does not really work.

Thanks so much for any suggestion.

Best,

Kai

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [remesh modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) will simplify your mesh and remove the smaller holes and at least some of the internal mesh. You may need to apply the modifier and then manually clean up the bigger holes.

A more manual approach is to retopologize the mesh, which is a common method used to cleanup sculpts. You can use the [built-in snapping tools](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/precision/snap.html), the [bsurfaces addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5) that is included with blender or CGCookies [retopoflow](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/retopoflow/) to make it easier.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "some of the internal mesh"? Is the modifier somewhat capable of sorting out the internal faces/external volume? Could you specify a bit?

Comment: It will normally stick to the outer surface of the mesh, not follow the smaller holes inward. Some of the larger holes will end up as depressions. The higher the octree depth the more it will go down the holes. It is a modifier so you can try it and see how it does without affecting your mesh.